# Load Excel file with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, meteor

How can I read the data from a worksheet in an Excel file using javascript?

I have found https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx. I can get data with

```
// require modules
var fs = Npm.require('fs');
var path = Npm.require('path');
var xlsx = Meteor.npmRequire('xlsx');

// set base path
var basepath = path.resolve('.').split('.meteor')[0];

// read workbook
var workbook = xlsx.readFile(basepath + "persons.xlsx");
var worksheet = workbook.Sheets['Sheet1'];
worksheet = xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet);

var sum = 0;
for (var cell in worksheet) {
  console.log(worksheet[cell]);
  sum += 1;
}
console.log(sum);
```

but do I really have to convert it to json? I don't know how to loop through each row in the worksheet and the documentation doesn't provide much information on how to "navigate" in the loaded sheets.

Is this the best package for this? Is it significantly faster/more lightweight to use csv files instead of Excel files? I have to load data from a file into my web app very often so I need the most optimal way to do it.

## Edit

When I look in the files how they are translating the Excel file to csv, I can find this function:

```
function sheet_to_csv(sheet, opts) {
    var out = "", txt = "", qreg = /"/g;
    var o = opts == null ? {} : opts;
    if(sheet == null || sheet["!ref"] == null) return "";
    var r = safe_decode_range(sheet["!ref"]);
    var FS = o.FS !== undefined ? o.FS : ",", fs = FS.charCodeAt(0);
    var RS = o.RS !== undefined ? o.RS : "\n", rs = RS.charCodeAt(0);
    var row = "", rr = "", cols = [];
    var i = 0, cc = 0, val;
    var R = 0, C = 0;
    for(C = r.s.c; C <= r.e.c; ++C) cols[C] = encode_col(C);
    for(R = r.s.r; R <= r.e.r; ++R) {
        row = "";
        rr = encode_row(R);
        for(C = r.s.c; C <= r.e.c; ++C) {
            val = sheet[cols[C] + rr];
            txt = val !== undefined ? ''+format_cell(val) : "";
            for(i = 0, cc = 0; i !== txt.length; ++i) if((cc = txt.charCodeAt(i)) === fs || cc === rs || cc === 34) {
                txt = "\"" + txt.replace(qreg, '""') + "\""; break; }
            row += (C === r.s.c ? "" : FS) + txt;
        }
        out += row + RS;
    }
    return out;
```

so it seems they are using

```
for(R = r.s.r; R <= r.e.r; ++R) {
    for(C = r.s.c; C <= r.e.c; ++C) {
```

to loop through the rows and columns but I don't understand the syntax. I cannot find `r.s.c`, `r.e.c`, and `r.e.r`.

It seems I can get A1 with `worksheet[{c:0, r:0}]` and B2 with `worksheet[{c:1, r:1}]` but I don't know how to loop through all rows/cols when I don't know the total number of rows and cols.

Comment: Looking at the documentation for js-xlsx it looks like there is significant documentation on how to work with workbooks and sheets:

https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx#working-with-the-workbook

Have you tried those options? You would just iterate over the cells you want to access, I assume with a loop, or generation. If you have a more specific question, please update and I'm sure someone can help.

Comment: But I can only see how to iterate over cells (as in my code above). Should I use modulus calculation to determine the row and column number? I don't know how to just loop over the rows and decide the column numbers

Comment: I assume you know which columns/rows you want information from, right? So you can just do a double-nested loop to either loop over the cells in a row, row by row, or the cells in a column, column by column, and end the loop when you hit a blank cell. Of course, you do need a function to construct the names of the cells, too.

Comment: Would it help for me to illustrate what I mean?

Comment: Yes it would help alot. Because I thought I could just use `for (row in worksheet) { for (col in row) { console.log(worksheet[row][col]); } }`

Comment: I have updated my question a little

Comment: It depends how much you know about your data. You could do a loop and exit the loop once you hit an empty cell, if that works given your data. If you know nothing at all about your data, you might want to loop just loop over all elements in the worksheet.